# Magento 2.3 Ui grid not working when store column is present

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, store-view, export

I have created a custom grid using UI component. **"Store" column** is one of the columns.
The issue is, when there is Store column, export function is not working.
The error comes from the following path

> vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/MetadataProvider.php
>   function: getRowData()

What I want to know is, whether there is an issue in my implementation or this is a Magento issue?
Thanks

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_uploader_listing.test_uploader_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button name="add">
            <url path="*/*/new"/>
            <class>primary</class>
            <label translate="true">Add New</label>
        </button>
    </buttons>
    <spinner>test_uploader_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>test_uploader_listing.test_uploader_listing_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="test_uploader_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">test_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>test_test::test_manage</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="test_uploader_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>test_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <settings>
        <sticky>true</sticky>
    </settings>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <settings>
            <templates>
                <filters>
                    <select>
                        <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</param>
                        <param name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</param>
                    </select>
                </filters>
            </templates>
        </settings>
        <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                <options class="Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options"/>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                <imports>
                    <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <action name="delete">
            <settings>
                <confirm>
                    <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
                    <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                </confirm>
                <url path="test/icons/massDelete"/>
                <type>delete</type>
                <label translate="true">Delete</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
        <action name="disable">
            <settings>
                <url path="test/icons/massDisable"/>
                <type>disable</type>
                <label translate="true">Disable</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
        <action name="enable">
            <settings>
                <url path="test/icons/massEnable"/>
                <type>enable</type>
                <label translate="true">Enable</label>
            </settings>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="test_uploader_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <settings>
            <indexField>test_id</indexField>
            <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
            <resizeDefaultWidth>55</resizeDefaultWidth>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="test_id" sortOrder="100">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="name" sortOrder="150">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="store_id" class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Store View</label>
            <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
        <settings>
            <options class="Magento\Cms\Model\Block\Source\IsActive"/>
            <filter>select</filter>
            <editor>
                <editorType>select</editorType>
            </editor>
            <dataType>select</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
    </column>        
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="test\test\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TestActions">
        <settings>
            <indexField>icon_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

collection file

> vendor/mode/RsourceModel/Files/Collection

```
class Collection extends AbstractCollection

{  
protected $_idFieldName = 'test_id';

/**
 * Load data for preview flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_previewFlag;

/**
 * Event prefix
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventPrefix = 'test_test_Grid_Collection';

/**
 * Event object
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventObject = 'test_Grid_Collection';

/**
 * _construct
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('test\test\Model\Files', 'test\test\Model\ResourceModel\Files');
    $this->_map['fields']['test_id'] = 'main_table.test_id';
    $this->_map['fields']['store'] = 'store_table.store_id';
}

/**
 * Set first store flag
 *
 * @param bool $flag
 * @return $this
 */
public function setFirstStoreFlag($flag = false)
{
    $this->_previewFlag = $flag;
    return $this;
}


public function addStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin = true)
{
    if (!$this->getFlag('store_filter_added')) {
        $this->performAddStoreFilter($store, $withAdmin);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Perform operations after collection load
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    //$entityMetadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(PageInterface::class);
    $this->performAfterLoad('test_store', 'test_id');
    $this->_previewFlag = false;

    return parent::_afterLoad();
}

/**
 * Perform operations before rendering filters
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    //$entityMetadata = $this->metadataPool->getMetadata(PageInterface::class);
    $this->joinStoreRelationTable('test_store', 'test_id');
}
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: which code you are referring? My grid is working well. this is a basic grid.this happens when export is functioning

Comment: Ui-Component for export button and collection file

Comment: Hi @HIrenKadivar i have updated the post

Comment: add Collection.php

Comment: done @HIrenKadivar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90659/discussion-between-hiren-kadivar-and-kevin).